# How to stop particular service in Hadoop environment

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

How to stop particular daemon in Hadoop environment? Assume I want to stop only particular Data-node in my cluster ! How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Below command to stop singe datanode. Run this on datanode server

./hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode

Below command to start singe datanode

./hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode